# Can this argument be enough?

Tags: design, design-patterns, c++, performance

We have two C++ classes named `Important` and `Small`

The class `Small` use a few methods and attributes from the class `Important`, but not all.

Since our application is performance critical, instead of copying all attributes (possibly pointers) of `Important` that are needed by `Small` and redefine the few methods in `Small`, we decided to just let `Small` hold a pointer on `Important`.

Can performance justify such a design choice?

Comment: Run a profiler on it, and see if it matters.

Comment: Well, It does. We had an Idea of creating a composition inside `Important` by considering that `Important` HAS A side `A` and provide only  a pointer on `A` to `Small`. However this solution is not viable as there are other classes similar to small (Small2, Small3) each of them need a different part of structures hold by `Important`, and those even have non-nul intersections :(

Comment: If adequate performance is a requirement of your project, and the only way to get that adequate performance is by your design choice, then yes, the design choice is justified.  Why would it be otherwise?  That is the very essence of the phrase "premature optimization;" code using sensible design techniques, and then break the design only when and where you need to to achieve adequate performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In line with RAII, I would certainly make sure that you had a reference-counting smart pointer (`shared_ptr`) instead of a raw pointer. Besides that, there's nothing inherently wrong with what you've described.

However, as many people have noted already, it is impossible to give an accurate answer without two things:

- Code. Are you turning your code into an incomprehensible mess when there is an easier option? The heck if I know. I haven't seen your code. I am not asking for code (I wouldn't read it even if you gave it to me), but I am asking you to take this advice with a grain of salt. Just because I said there was nothing wrong doesn't mean it is right.
- Performance Numbers. Is this really something that will affect the performance of your program? Without solid numbers I can't say for sure and *neither can you*.

Answer (score 0):

> Can performance justify such a design choice?

With so little information, I think the advice is going to be pushed towards suggestions of profiling and measuring and warnings about premature optimization. But I'll try to give you the benefit of the doubt.

Let's apply a data-oriented design mindset which begins with the idea of the most optimal data representation, and works our way up to interfaces from there. The most useful aspect of this exercise is still going to be the public interfaces we design, the consideration of data representations is mainly to ensure that we have an interface that can leave wiggle room to optimize without cascading breakages in the system.

**Data-Oriented Design**

> Since our application is performance critical, instead of copying all
>   attributes (possibly pointers) of Important that are needed by Small
>   and redefine the few methods in Small, we decided to just let Small
>   hold a pointer on Important.

Some assumptions I'm going to make to narrow the scope:

- There are a boatload of these `Small*` instances.
- The initialization phase where they are created as a subset of `Important's` data is separate and outside of your critical code paths, not interleaved (otherwise your existing suggestion might be the best route).
- The critical path is going to loop through a boatload of these `Small` instances.
- The fields of `Important` itself, outside of the subset represented by `Small`, are cold.
- The fields of `Important` do not change past the initialization step (their pointees could change if there are pointer fields, but the pointer addresses would not change).

**One-to-One**

Provided that there's a one-to-one relationship of a `Small*'s` subset of data fields to an `Important` (no redundancy), then typically the fastest way to go is to actually copy and duplicate the data of `Important` in small.

Since `Important` is cold data according to our assumptions, that allows `Small` to take on a more contiguous nature, and for more of the relevant data to fit into a cache line without being intermixed with irrelevant data.

**Many-to-One**

If that's wrong and there's a whole lot of redundancy between `Small*` instances (i.e., a many-to-one relationship between `Small` references to an `Important` field), then duplicating the data could do more harm than good.

In that case, pointing to `Important` can start to show a favorable advantage, as we're playing to temporal locality with `Important` fields often sitting in a cache line and reducing `Small` down to the size of a single pointer.

**To Duplicate or Not to Duplicate**

So the choice of whether or not to duplicate depends on the level of redundancy and whether the initialization phase of a small is outside of the critical paths. If you want to know to what level of redundancy, consider the total size of all `Small*` instances if those fields from `Important` were duplicated. If that size is not larger than the sum of all `Important` fields, then copying the relevant fields to `Small` might be a safe bet (provided `Important` doesn't need to be accessed in critical paths at all, that it's truly cold after that point).

With little or no redundancy, and `Important` being cold, then actually hot/cold field splitting with redundancy to get the hot side of the split can actually help a lot (as counter-intuitive as it may seem).

Last but not least, there should be a boatload of `Small*` instances being instantiated and accessed. If there aren't, then this is worrying about something that shouldn't be worried about, as you'll likely benefit a lot from temporal locality either way.